# Chrome Extension DOM Completely loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have tried several attempts to make sure DOM is completely loaded before trying to work with DOM, I can never seem to get the div counts to match up.

My test is, I run the page with dev tools open and once page is done I open console up and run same code(document.getElementsByTagName('div').length) and they are off!!

Anyone have any clue? The only thing that seem sto work is when I set a timeout, and I want to try to stay away from that...unless thats the only solutions, I have already searched articles and attempted several solutions, but no luck...

Here some some attempts...

1) manifest file has content_scripts/run_at : "document_start"

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var count = document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
 console.log(count);
}, true);
```

2) manifest file has content_scripts/run_at : "document_end"; I basically send a message to background.js who then send message back run function.

```
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
 });

 chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(request);
  divCount();
 });

function divCount() {
 var count = document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
 console.log(count);
}
```

2) manifest file has content_scripts/run_at : "document_end"; I basically send a message to background.js who then

content.js

```
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
 });
```

background.js

```
 chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
       code: "console.log($('div').length)"
       }, function(data) {
     console.log(data);
    });
 });
```

I have also tried this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function( tabId , info ) {
 console.log(tabId, info);
 if ( info.status == "complete" ) {

 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
  code: "console.log($('div').length)"
  }, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
 });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

DOMContentLoaded - can occur before all the scripts have processed so if you have any JS that adds in elements this might explain the issue.

However I don't see why you are having an issue, you are using document_start to do some work, however this is way to early to be doing what you are doing.  I am not sure why you just don't include the logic in your DOMContentLoaded in the same script as your document_end...